# Is it safe to keep nonce/hash codes in .htacces file or creating random nonce/hash codes separately for each webpage visited by user?

Tags: .htaccess, server-side, content-security-policy

I'm setting up content-security-policy on my website. And after much exploration i m little confused as to where do i put CSP code. Should i place it individually on every web page which is heavy work or should i put the nonce/hash code in .htaccess file? And how can i generate random nonces/hash code each time somebody is on the website?

I have already tried placing the CSP in every web page and it takes a lot of time to get it working, not to mention the edits on every script link and inline elements.

Following is the code that i have used: (example)
...
script-src 'nonce-4AEemGb0xJptoIGFP3Nd'

...
Should i keep the nonce code in .htaccess file or keep separate for each individual pages on the site.

Answer (score 1):

A random nonce must, by definition, be generated on every page load; nonce means "number used once".  So you must generate the page programmatically, not use raw .html files.  A static nonce (a "nmany"?) defeats the purpose of nonces, and provides no security whatsoever.

A hash, on the other hand, is static, because it's a representation of a specific script.